# PHP memory_get_usage is larger than memory_limit

Tags: php, memory-management, memory-limit

My PHP application has been running a bit slow and it's not very memory efficient at the moment. My whole server has been going down very often and I think I have this app to blame. I thought I'd monitor the memory usage and check how much I have as a limit:

```
echo 'Memory in use: ' . memory_get_usage() . ' ('. memory_get_usage()/1024 .'M) <br>';
echo 'Peak usage: ' . memory_get_peak_usage() . ' ('. memory_get_peak_usage()/1024 .'M) <br>';
echo 'Memory limit: ' . ini_get('memory_limit') . '<br>';
```

This shows the following:

```
Memory in use: 629632 (614.921875M) 
Peak usage: 635696 (620.796875M) 
Memory limit: 128M
```

How could this be? Memory in use is WAY larger than memory limit? Either something's really broken or I do not understand at all how the `memory_limit` setting works (or `memory_get_usage()` )

Thank you all.

Comment: [memory_get_usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) returns it in bytes, what you are calculating there is actually in `kB`. Divide it by `1024` again to have it in `MB`

Comment: Your math is off by an order of magnitude. Divide it by another 1024 to get megabytes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[memory_get_usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) returns it in bytes, what you are calculating there is actually in `kB`. Divide it by `1024` again to have it in `MB`

Same goes for [memory_get_peak_usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php)

e.g.

```
echo 'Memory in use: ' . memory_get_usage() . ' ('. ((memory_get_usage() / 1024) / 1024) .'M) <br>';
```

Comment: I should quit my job :|

Comment: Can happen to the best of us ;)

Comment: `memory_get_usage()` is about allocated memory, not used memory

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub does allocated memory count for the script `memory_limit` ?

Comment: @beppe9000 `memory_get_usage()` returns **Current** allocated memory by **single** script while `memory_limit` sets **Maximum** amount of memory a **single** script is Allowed to allocate.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub so I can use `memory_get_usage()` to check if I am about to hit the `memory_limit` and it will be the same value that is used internally? For example `if((memory_get_usage()/128000000)>=0.9) break;` ?

Comment: @beppe9000 Yes.

Comment: If the parameter is not set or FALSE only the used memory is reported.

Comment: I copied this and my answer was 80M wtf??? think the issues is real for my case.